# docker-compose scaleable way to provide environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am searching for a scaleable solution to the problem of having numerous possible environments for a containerised app. Let's say am creating a web app and I have the usual deployment environments, `develop, testing, production` but I also have multiple instances of the app for different clients, `client1, client2, client3` etc.

This quickly becomes a mess if I have to create separate docker-compose files:

```
docker-compose-client1-develop.yml
docker-compose-client1-testing.yml
docker-compose-client1-production.yml
docker-compose-client2-develop.yml
...
```

Breaking the client specific configuration into a `.env` file and dockers variable substitution gets me most of the way there, I can now have one `docker-compose.yml` file and just do:

```
services:
  webapp:
    image: 'myimage:latest'
    env_file:
     - ./clients/${CLIENT}.env  # client specific .env file
    environment:
     - DEPLOY  # develop, testing, production
```

so now I just need the `CLIENT` and `DEPLOY` environment variables set when I run `docker-compose up` which is fine, but I'm wondering about a convenient way to pass those environment variables in to `docker-compose`. There's the potential (at least during development) for a decent amount of context-switching. Is there a tidy way to pass in different `CLIENT` and `DEPLOY` env vars to `docker-compose up` every time I run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is to set environment variables *per-command*.

Are you running on Linux? Take a look at [`env`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uenv.htm) command. Just prepend your `docker-compose` command line like this:

```
env CLIENT=client1 DEPLOY=production docker-compose ...
```

On Windows, you may have to do something more complicated (like [this](https://superuser.com/a/950944)), but there could be simpler ways.

Comment: Personally I'm running on Linux so this works great for me.There's the possibility of some developers being on Windows which makes it awkward. I was hoping for a portable solution but I suspect one may not exist for this method

Comment: Environment variable are inherently OS-specific. I'm afraid there isn't a cross-platform solution (but you could always write a wrapper)

Comment: went with this solution in the end, wrote a thin python wrapper around `docker-compose` that can set the environment vars for our windows users and linux users can either use that or just use `env`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [docker-compose file extending](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#specifying-multiple-compose-files)?

For instance you can have base `docker-compose.yml` file which is the production one and multiple extending files where you only change what needs to be overloaded:

**docker-compose.dev.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  webapp:
    env_file: path_to_the_file_env
```

Then you simply use both:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up
```

To spin up the production it's as easy as:

```
docker-compose up
```

I personally use this technique a lot in many of my projects.

Comment: It's definitely an option. My only issue with it is that it would end up typing something along the lines of `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml -f docker-compose.client1.yml up -d` which is a little long winded. I was hoping for something like `docker-compose -e CLIENT="client1" -e DEPLOY="develop" up -d` which is only a little shorter but a bit more explicit

Comment: You still have to create a file for every client and a file for every deployment environment.